# Why two consecutive gather instruction perform worse than equivalent elementary ops?

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, sse, avx2

I am upgrading some code from SSE to AVX2. In general I can see that gather instructions are quite useful and benefit performance. However I encountered a case where gather instructions are less efficient than decomposing the gather operations into simpler ones.

In the code below, I have a vector of int32 `b`, a vector of double `xi` and 4 int32 indices packed in a 128 bit register `bidx`. I need to gather first from vector `b`, than from vector `xi`. I.e., in pseudo code, I need to do:

```
__m128i i = b[idx];
__m256d x = xi[i];
```

In the function below, I implement this in two ways using an `#ifdef`: via gather instructions, yielding a throughput of 290 Miter/sec and via elementary operations, yielding a throughput of 325 Miter/sec.

Can somebody explain what is going on? Thanks

```
inline void resolve( const __m256d& z, const __m128i& bidx, int32_t j
                    , const int32_t *b, const double *xi, int32_t* ri )
{

    __m256d x;
    __m128i i;

#if 0  // this code uses two gather instructions in sequence

    i = _mm_i32gather_epi32(b, bidx, 4));  // i = b[bidx]
    x = _mm256_i32gather_pd(xi, i, 8);     // x = xi[i]

#else  // this code does not use gather instructions

    union {
            __m128i vec;
            int32_t i32[4];
    } u;
    x = _mm256_set_pd
            ( xi[(u.i32[3] = b[_mm_extract_epi32(bidx,3)])]
            , xi[(u.i32[2] = b[_mm_extract_epi32(bidx,2)])]
            , xi[(u.i32[1] = b[_mm_extract_epi32(bidx,1)])]
            , xi[(u.i32[0] = b[_mm_cvtsi128_si32(bidx)  ])]
            );
    i = u.vec;

#endif

    // here we use x and i
    __m256  ps256 = _mm256_castpd_ps(_mm256_cmp_pd(z, x, _CMP_LT_OS));
    __m128  lo128 = _mm256_castps256_ps128(ps256);
    __m128  hi128 = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ps256, 1);
    __m128  blend = _mm_shuffle_ps(lo128, hi128, 0 + (2<<2) + (0<<4) + (2<<6));
    __m128i lt    = _mm_castps_si128(blend);  // this is 0 or -1
    i = _mm_add_epi32(i, lt);
    _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(ri)+j, i);
}
```

Comment: Gather instructions are very slow. I don't know what processor you have, but on Haswell, I've never found a single case where gather was actually faster than manual scalar code. Things are supposed to be better with Broadwell and Skylake, but I haven't tested since.

Comment: I am testing on Haswell. According to my tests, when I have a standalone gather instruction rather than two consecutive ones, performance improves. For instance, _mm256_i32gather_ps is faster than the manual version, both using extract (which is the worst) or using unions.

Comment: The reciprocal throughput of gather is not available at Intel intrinsic guide, but Agner Fog had measured `_mm_i32gather_epi32` to be 9 clocks, and not yet listed for `_mm256_i32gather_pd`. My guess is, it could take ~ 18 clocks to do 2 consecutive gathers, and your code below is not long enough to hide the latency. You can `-S` with your compiler and check what is being generated for different version.

Comment: Before the `_mm256_i32gather_pd` instruction can execute, it has to wait for the `_mm_i32gather_epi32` instruction to finish, incurring a large latency.  The longer way without gather doesn't have this delay, since the larger number of instructions can schedule better as it works on smaller chunks of the larger problem.

Comment: If you see Anger Fog, gather instructions use `p0 p1 p23 p5` respectively. It cause a big delay. I use `skylake` and have tested many program with and with out gathering. If Intel provide a separated execution core for gathering or increase the shuffling execution it might increase the gather performance. But now gather is just a new name that use shuffling and permuting as a dummy. The best choice is using `shuffle`, `insert` and `permute` to yield the expected performance.

Answer (score -1):

Since your 'resolve' function is marked as inline I suppose it's called in a high frequency loop. Then you might also have a look at the dependencies of the input parameters from each other outside the 'resolve' function. The compiler might be able to optimize the inlined code better across loop boundaries when using the scalar code variant.